# Notepad++, Run command and open output in new tab

Tags: notepad++, pipe

Is there any way to execute a command from `notepad++` and have the results piped back into the program in a new tab?

Comment: AFAIK, this *can* be done with a plugin - whether or not said plugin exists already is an entirely different matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your program outputs plain text and you can run batch files...

1. Create a batch file (e.g. dir.bat) which pipes the results of your command to a temporary file, then opens the file in Notepad++ e.g.

   ```
   dir > tmp
   "C:\path_to_notepad_plus_plus\notepad++" tmp
   ```

   (replace **dir** with your command and add an extension to tmp to syntax-highlight it appropriately).
2. In Notepad++, select Run > Run... and browse for your batch file.
3. If you use it often, consider saving it as a macro (Run > Run... > Save...) which you can access with a keyboard shortcut or under the *Run* menu.

Comment: Don't name the batch file `dir.bat` because `dir` is the name of built in command.

Answer (score 2):

For more flexible, you can install the [NppExec plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppExec/). The easiest way to install it is through the built-in Plugin Manager:

1. Select Plugins / Plugin Manager / Show Plugin Manager
2. Put a checkmark next to NppExec
3. Click Install

After that, the fun begins. This tutorial is a good starting point on how to use this powerful plugin: https://micksmix.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/format-your-perl-scripts-using-perltidy-and-notepad/

It should work with any command-line utility that outputs text to the console.

Comment: Sorry, but it did not answer the OP's question of how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you cannot install plugins and can only use Notepad++'s Run command is to utilize piping the output to the Windows clipboard which  allows you to paste the output wherever you want.

As an example I use the following to checkout perforce files using the command line tool:

```
cmd /c "cd /d $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) & C:\Progra~1\Perforce\p4.exe edit $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH) | clip"
```

The base of this is `cmd /c "your_commands | clip"` which runs a command, terminates the program when done and sends all the output to the Windows clipboard via the command `clip`.

After the command runs you can paste the contents of your clipboard somewhere (such as a new file) if you need or want the output.

Comment: Good tip, but I think you should explain that `clip` is a command included with Windows.